# Why does Keras convert the input shape from (3,3) to (?,3,3)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dimensions

I am currently trying to get custom keras layers to work, you can see a simplified version here:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        print("input_shape: "+str(input_shape))
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        print("input tensor: "+str(x))
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)


inputs = Input(shape=(3,3), dtype='float', name='inputs')
results = MyLayer(input_shape=(3,3))(inputs)
```

The resulting console output is this:

```
input_shape: (None, 3, 3)
input tensor: Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(?, 3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

As you can see, the input_shape that the layer gets is not (3,3) as I specified but actually (None,3,3). Why is that? 
The shape of the input tensor is also shaped ( *?,* 3,3) which I thought to be a consequence of the weird input_shape ( *None,* 3,3). But the input tensor also has this shape with a third dimension if you replace `super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)` with `super(MyLayer, self).build((3,3))`. What is this mysterious third dimension keras automatically adds and why does it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing mysterious, it is the batch dimension, since `keras` (and most DL frameworks), make computations on batches of data at a time, since this increases parallelism, and it maps directly to batches in Stochastic Gradient Descent.

Your layer needs to support computation on batches, so the batch dimension is always present in input and output data, and it is automatically added by `keras` to the `input_shape`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Now what I'm wondering, can I somehow reference the batch size in my call function? In my particular example, I don't just use K.dot to compute the output but need to flatten the input using K.flatten. How can I flatten every input in the batch without knowing the batch size?

Comment: You can use K.reshape(input_tensor, (-1,9)). Here, using -1 makes the K.reshape function to automatically determine the shape of that axis according to the the shape of the other axes. In your case, since you want to transform from (None, 3, 3) to (None, 9), you can use K.reshape(input_tensor, (-1, (3x3))). As an additional note, you can use -1 for only one axis when specifying the shape tuple you pass to the K.reshape() function.

Comment: @Poly-nom-nom-noo I think K.flatten already works batch-wise, most if not all backend functions work that way. So you do not need to do anything special to support batches.

Answer (score 0):

This newly added dimension refers to the batch dimension, i.e., in your case, you will be passing batches of 3x3 dimensional tensors. This additional `None` dimension refers to the batch dimension, which is unknown during the creation of the graph.

If you have a look at the Input layer explanation in Core Layers webpage for Keras,
https://keras.io/layers/core/, you will see that the shape argument you are passing when creating the Input layer is defined as the following:

> shape: A shape tuple (integer), not including the batch size. For instance, shape=(32,) indicates that the expected input will be batches of 32-dimensional vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the batch size, you can do this instead:

inputs = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size,height,width,channel))